# Average number of database tables (SQL Server)?

Tags: sql-server

I'm just wondering how many companies utilize 100+, 1,000+, or 10,000+ or more database tables/views/objects (but not stored procedures). I know this is a hard question to answer and that the utility of doing this depends on many factors, along with the company size and the type of application that the structures support.

But, I'm working at a company now on a team that supports 1 application with nearly 12,000 tables according to my query, and 17,000 tables according to my coworker (let's say it's 15k tables. I don't know why our numbers are different & I may not have access to everything he does).

My experience and understanding is that most companies "usually" have between maybe 20 to a few hundred database tables at most, which would normally power 1 or several software applications.

I'm trying to identify various complexities of projects being delayed within our (one, single) software application that produces so many tables and views. Am I right to estimate that 15k relational/SQL server views is *a lot* of tables and views? ...a lot more than what's typical or average?

I know it's a lot because our storage team refuses to back up our databases a lot of the time because it takes too long (like 10 or 15 hours). Is this really an absolute anomoly in the industry like I'm gathering? What's average, or an average range?

And no, our tables are not that normalized, which is in some cases out of our control since many are auto-generated by software applications (although I think it's somewhat within our control too which is another story).

Comment: I don't think this is a question for StackOverflow but rather a chat of some sort. But 12,000 tables seems excessive. How many tables are used for production/reports?

Comment: It's our Production database that has 15k tables/views. Test environments (if migrated/copied exactly) would each have that same amount as well.  Supposedly they're all used, and deleting them causes system failures... although this is what I'm investigating. I keep telling people that's it's a struggle having so many structures, but if it's a normal company problem then I'll be more open to workarounds or dealing with it, rather than pushing for extra accommodations.

Comment: Without knowing more I would guess that tables are calling other tables especially if your company using a lot of stored procedures. An easier and more maintainable solution would be the use of hash/temp tables. I would start by going through some of the most used sprocs and investigate how many tables it uses.

Comment: Ok...the funny thing is I don't think we have "that" many stored procedures (maybe 200), and those were all manually made I believe. But the tables are actually themselves "Views" in a way (they are result tables of joins of other tables) which unfortunately I actually need to understand as well as I can in order to do development work, since they all actually represent useful things. It just seems like a lot, so I'm just trying to quantify "a lot" if I can :)

Comment: "refuses to back up our databases"  ... this made me giggle.   If you value your data, the storage team needs to create a solution.

Comment: Lol, thanks John for the input. I mean...they do back up/copy/migrate the prod data, we just really have to push and it's rare, and we have to work hard to schedule it around other processing times. It just all seems unusual to me as a new employee. I guess we just have a lot of data. Glad you got a kick of out that :)

Comment: It would be a better practice to do those joins in sprocs and only use those tables when you need the data from them. It looks like a lot of the tables are intermediary tables which could be converted to temp tables inside of a sproc which creates the tables and uses the data when needed.

Comment: Listening to your description, I am struck by the pure absurdity of this structure. Since one table can be a "view" of one or more other tables, are these data steps maintained by triggers? Or is there an occasional build step that rebuilds the tables? Or does the application update all of the appropriate tables when it updates one of the base tables?   Originally, I was thinking that this needed to use more DBs to split tables by functionality (or at least more schemas), but the extended description is hurting my head. Hopefully you have a good data dictionary, or at least food naming?

Comment: Edeki Okoh, that makes sense.  I don't think we have control over it, but I'm glad to learn the usefulness of what you said since I have also seen companies do that (the stored procs) and I didn't know why at the time. Thanks!

Comment: Laughing Vergil, thanks for your input!  There are not good naming conventions...many tables are auto-generated by an application whose purpose is to help build SQL structures (it's like a SQL view configurer), and the tables are called "Table0001" and "HistoryTable500" and such, although in the actual application they are called "2019 Data Report for Sales" which could use 100s of them. Ideally I would understand them all, but that's not happening. We have many man-made tables as well. Nice to know that it's not just me thinking this setup is unusual. It helps me develop expectations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do agree that this is somewhat broad for SO but, none the less, will give you my opinion.
I have never seen a database with more than 300 tables, yet they were 200+GB in size.

Depending on the nature of the application it is not unusual to have intermediary tables, where the data is stored and must be preserved. Use case scenarios include batch processing and reporting.

In either case it is important to clean-up these tables to keep DB size manageable. Data is usually copied away after a period of time into another database and preserved.

Auto creation of tables with numbers in the name (Table0001) smells of legacy DB design (circa 1998) and/or bad design practice. In old days this may have been done for performance reasons when generating complex reports, that could then be queried many times. I imagine dynamic SQL is rife in the application and debugging problems is a nightmare.

You need to find out what they are created for (reporting or some other reason) and find out the policy for removing "old" tables. If the tables are created for reporting purpose I would suggest to create a new database to store these tables.

Comment: Thank you! I understand it's a "broad" question, however your answer along with some others are actually helpful. "I have never seen a database with more than 300 tables" helps, &I never thought about looking at GB/space. Our production DB contains 4,276 GB and 30 users. I probably don't need to do anything with this information but it stills help me develop realistic expectations as a developer. Knowing in which order to schedule tasks like migrations, backups, testing changes my development process (dev DB is so outdated, it's not that useful) which helps make a case for migrations. Helpful!

Comment: ...To answer some more of those questions, yes there is batch processing involved, and we do have "staging" tables although many of those thousands of tables are not for staging.They are just used for reporting, but there can be hundreds of them used within a single report.I like the idea of having a new database to store these.  Maybe a second database could work...I'll have to think about the logic since pre-processing and staging tables feed the thousands of tables which are used for the reports.

Comment: Finally, for this "In old days this may have been done for performance reasons when generating complex reports, that could then be queried many times. I imagine dynamic SQL is rife in the application and debugging problems is a nightmare."  That's good to know...maybe I can find out more about how that underlying system works with those Table0001 tables. And I haven't seen any dynamic SQL yet, however for me debugging is a nightmare because I don't even know where to begin in understanding the system in the first place. But, thanks for the help in getting me started!

Comment: To be honest you are stuck in a no mans land of a database design. With that many tables it is unsustainable without sufficient documentation which I bet does not exist. You should start with the most used reports and track the tables which are used for that report and convert the logic to a single sproc. Which sql version/provider are you using. sql server does have some capabilities to help with this. But manually this is something that will take years to finish based on what you are saying.

Comment: It is also possible that your company uses one database to host data of multiple applications with distinct operational goals. This is also not a good idea, as batch processing vs OLTP vs Reporting have distinct usage patterns that conflict with one another.